# How to avoid narrator and string to speech Overlapping in c#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, narrator

```
    Process process;

    // Read Contetnt Mouse click event
    private SpeechSynthesizer readerSpeak;
    private void btnSpeakContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(richTextBoxThanglish.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            if (process.HasExited == false)
                process.Kill();
            MessageBoxWrapper.ShowWarning("Textbox is Empty.", "ABTS", "Textbox is Empty.");
            process = Process.Start("narrator.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            if (process.HasExited == false)
                process.Kill();

            readerSpeak = new SpeechSynthesizer();                
            readerSpeak.SpeakAsync(richTextBoxThanglish.Text.ToString());

            if (process.HasExited == true)
                process = Process.Start("narrator.exe");
        }
    }       

    private void btnStopSpeak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (process.HasExited == true)
            process = Process.Start("narrator.exe");

        if (!(readerSpeak == null))
        {                
            readerSpeak.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Assume above program has two buttons call speakContent & stop_speak. I run narrator.exe process to get windows narrator.
I do want to speek the richtextbox content without overlapping voice. I know about Synchronos speak, but it will pause my app until speakContent get finish. I need this with SpeakAsyn().
Is there anyway to add silent in the voice narrator? Actually i need that text speech, after 3sec. I had use "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);". But still text overlapping occurs,
Means narrator & string to speech plays together.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do process related stuff in background thread... here's an example using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It's available in the WinForms toolbox in Visual Studio, so you should be able to just drag-and-drop onto your form.

Create a handler for the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event. This is where you'll call the other process in a background thread. You can wait for the process to complete here without your app stopping.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    process = Process.Start("narrator.exe");
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

When someone clicks the button to read, you can just check if the `BackgroundWorker` is currently running, and do nothing if that's the case.

```
if(this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have fixed it using key_Leave event.

Comment: If you'd like to, you can post an answer yourself (and accept it) to document how you fixed it (with code samples, etc), so anyone who has this problem in the future will know how to solve it.